# Adding nil to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsmutablearray

I am trying to create a NSMutableArray by reading in a .txt file and am having trouble setting the last element of the array to nil.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"namelist" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *list = [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSMutableArray *mutableList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:list];
```

I wanted to use NSMutableArray's function addObject, but that will not allow me to add nil. I also tried:

```
[mutableList addObject:[NSNull null]];
```

but that does not seem to work either. Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: What's wrong with NSNull approach? It seems it was designed to address exactly your problem...And why do you need your last element to be nil(or NSNull) anyway?

Comment: What error do you get when adding [NSNull null]?  Does it woerk if you use this: `NSMutableArray *mutableList = [list mutableCopy];`?

Comment: I think [NSNull null] might be working (I realized that the problem was that I was trying to print out a null value, which was causing the error). Here is another issue that stemmed from this problem: mutableList.count is returning 0, even if the list has elements in it (I even printed its contents out). Is this some sort of memory management problem? Being new to Objective-C and coming from Java, this is quite puzzling :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
NSMutableArray *mutableList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[mutableList addObjectsFromArray:list];
```

Hope this helps
jrtc27

Comment: I think just: `NSMutableArray *mutableList = [list mutableCopy];` is better

Comment: Very true ;) - didn't think of that. It is also a lot easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Per Apple's documentation on NSMutableArray.

```
addObject:

Inserts a given object at the end of the receiver.

- (void)addObject:(id)anObject
Parameters

anObject

    The object to add to the end of the receiver's content. **This value must not be nil.**
```

Reference

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html